# Stepper Motor drawing very low current from DRV8825

Tags: current, motor, current-measurement, stepper-motor

We are using a stepper motor which has a rated voltage of 2.7V and resistance of 2.7 ohms. This means that the rated current is 1 A. We have also set the current limit of the DRV8825 motor driver to 1A. We are running the motor with a 24V power supply. On the multimeter, the current value doesn't go beyond 250 mA. Clearly, something is not right since the motor should consume more current. Can someone help us solve this? Is there a particular way of measuring the current of the system?

In addition to using a multimeter, we added a 1-ohm resistor in series with the system and measured voltage across it using an oscilloscope. Even that is giving similar results that is low current. What could be the reason for this?

Why are we getting a low current reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8825.pdf ....read 8.3.2  This is a switching/chopper driver and I'd bet you are using it in micro-step mode.
Your multimeter is measuring the average or RMS current flowing and does not see the peak.

The current point you set on the DRV8825 is the PEAK current that will flow from the PWM.
If you are measuring the current (250 mA) from your 24 V supply line then you are drawing about 6 W of power. 
The stepper motor is 1 * 2.7 or a little under 3 W.
Two windings gives you a bit less than 6 W maximum ....so sounds about right.

In microstepping mode the current will follow a sine wave so will move from zero to peak as the stepper moves.

[image]

Read the datasheet Table 2 
Notice that when Winding A is maximum Winding B is zero when microstepping.

Comment: Thanks Jack. For this particular motor, yes I am using the microstepping mode but there are other motors in the system on which we are giving full steps and even then I am getting a lower current. So using the oscilloscope we should measure peak to peak values of the sine wave and that should give us the right value ?

Comment: @Soumil07. You could use an Oscilloscope ...but the data sheet gives you a formula that relates winding current I(chop) to the current limit set. Read 8.3.2 as I said in the answer.